# Two different "Home" items in custom menus dashboard section

Tags: menus

Following the [WP documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), I created a page named "Home" and set it as the Front Page of my website. But now I have 2 different "home" items in custom menus: one corresponding to my new page, and one "custom link" apparently generated by default.

This redundancy makes me think that this is now the best way to proceed. Yet I merely followed the doc. Am I missing something? Is there a way to have a page with a custom template as the front page (not just a "front-page.php" template but a true WP page) and yet not have this redundancy?

Comment: You could create a [custom page template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), assign that to the page "Home" and assign "Home" to the Front page setting.